# Force.com public API Governor limit error codes

Tags: api, errormessages

I am developing a public Force.com API (published using Force.com site) using Apex REST services. I am planning to list all possible errors (especially governor limit errors) that can be returned when this API is accessed by the clients.

One option is to test the service by passing inputs that will violate the governor limits. However testing some governor limits (API limit, concurrent session limit etc) would require additional effort or would have some impact.

Ideally it will be helpful if there is a document/article with error description for all the possible errors. In the absence of it, any suggestions to get this list in short time? Appreciate your inputs in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

The Partner API has fairly complete documentation on the possible exceptions that might be returned. I suspect the REST API will have very similar errors.

See the following codes that are defined in the Partner API WSDL

- [ExceptionCode](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm#i1421192)
- [StatusCode](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm#statuscode)

Answer (score 0):

Here is link of Salesforce Limits Quick Reference Guide. This link contains most of  limits(if not all).

https://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf

But one thing I would like to bring to your notice is, it would be really difficult to envision all possible errors and the handle them properly.